# flutter app change status bar to match same appbar

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Hi im trying to change the statusbar to match the color of my appbar in flutter but i dont any luck im trying this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.black,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black),
```

but still my status bar looks like this:

[image]

but on iphone it shows the colors correctly

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import this

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

and add this code to the main widget tree :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // as you need dark or light
    ));

return MaterialApp(home: yourHomeWidgetWhereTheScaffoldIsDefined....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, im getting this https://ibb.co/6HPFrLT.  still black status bar